# MVVM in WPF - UserControls and GMap.NET

Tags: .net, wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm, gmap.net

I have read almost all the tutorials and checked stack questions however I still do not know and do not understand how to manage WPF UserControls in MVVM, specially those provided by others like GMap.NET.

I am trying to follow MVVM pattern in my app, however I have no idea how to initialize and manage GMap.NET WPF control in it. In standard approach it requires management like this:

```
gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
gmap.DragButton = MouseButton.Left;
gmap.SetPositionByKeywords("Paris, France");
gmap.ShowCenter = false;
```

How can I do this without braking MVVM? Is it possible? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind.  Just expose properties on the user control for whatever your map needs and bind your view model to them. Whatever UI logic you need to perform do it in the codebehind of the user control.

Comment: @Will, so should I put code like `gmap.DragButton = MouseButton.Left;` in the code behind if it is not going to be touched from VM? I cannot access for instance`DragButton` from XAML.

Comment: Agreed, MVVM allows for codebehind, especially when configuring the behaviors of the buttons etc. at run time.  The View Model is only your data portion to be bound to items in the view.  Is there a Source or ItemSource property on GMAP?

Comment: UI code goes in your codebehind.  Don't go sticking it in your view models.

Comment: @JohnPeters there Is MapProvider (and this one is accessible from XAML). So As I understand, I can do kind of wrapper in a codebehind, and bind to that wrapper?

Comment: Would anyone of you be so kind and give me basic example, or reply question? There are more people like me waiting for answer.

Comment: Why don't you put all the code you have posted in your question in the view? Is there any property of the GMap Control that you need to be able to control from the view model?

Comment: @mm8, Yes, of course. I need to manage it from the ViewModel. For example adding and removing markers, search by location...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, any code that just initializes the view can be placed in code behind.

If possible, properties from the view model should be bound the view. That is the prefered way and should beat down the most use cases.

However, some controls are complex and have an "advanced" API that consists not only of dependency properties, but also of methods and event.

If it is required to call "view methods" from the view model, the event-based approch works fine. Becuase the view knowns the view model, it can subscribe to events on the view model (e.g. in the DataContextChanged event). (see also [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847860/how-to-call-method-in-window-xaml-cs-from-viewmodel-cs-without-introducing))
**Example:** You want to call the method `gmap.SetPositionByKeywords` from the view model. Just give the view model an event `RequestSetPositionByKeyWords`, let the view subscibe to that method and call `gmap.SetPositionByKeywords` if the event has been raised. Parameters and return values can be transfered by event args. That is a nice approch which respects the MVVM principals.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. After trying some variants it's worked!

In my VM I have: `public event EventHandler<ViewEventArgs> MapSearchEvent;` and `private void MapSearch(string searchString) { MapSearchEvent?.Invoke(this, new ViewEventArgs(searchString)); }`

In My V I have: `vm.MapSearchEvent += MapSearch;` and my method: `private void MapSearch(object sender, ViewModels.ViewEventArgs e) { gmap.SetPositionByKeywords(e.ParameterString); }`

If that brakes the MVVM somewhere, please tell me.

Comment: Sounds good. It doesn't break MVVM because the VM remains independent from the view :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can also create the control inside the viewmodel:

```
GMapControl vmGmapControl{get;set;}
```

in the constructor:

```
vmGmapControl=new GmapControl();
//GMap control initialization logic...
```

and bind the view:

```
<UserControl Content="{Binding vmGmapControl}"/>
```

It may not follow the MVVM but otherwise you will have to rewrite all properties that you plan to use that are currently not bindable to dependency properties (the Markers property for example).