# Global access to WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have tried many options for a long time and that is the last one that comes to my mind, so I will try to ask:
I am trying to develop an MVVM project in WPF and I have downloaded a ready-to-use WPF control ([GMap.NET](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMapControl.cs)). However, this control is not prepared to use it in MVVM and I am a newbie in that, so I do not want to modify a source code on my own. The control requires to set many parameters (not accessible through XAML, so I cannot simply bind them), and call some functions on control object. So here goes my question:

How  can I access a WPF control instance from any place from the code and manage it from there?

Particularly, I want to access a View element from ViewModel part and I know that it brakes the pattern, but I have no idea how to avoid it and I am running out of time.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, is wrong with my question?

Comment: The control has a lot of dependency properties.. therefore it can be used in XAML using MVVM. What exactly are you trying to archive which is not possible?

Comment: @JanDotNet, here is my more concrete question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152773/mvvm-in-wpf-usercontrols-and-gmap-net
I've asked this in hope to get more general solution.

Comment: *I want to access a View element from ViewModel part* that isn't mvvm, so if you want to do that, knock your socks off.  Do whatever you need to do however you need to do it. Really, the pattern serves us, we don't serve the pattern.  The answer below is the **only answer** that exists for this situation, if you want to keep to the pattern. There's no need to ask a third question on the subject :/

Comment: @Will, The problem is already solved in the specific case as GMap.NET in another question. And the answer for general case is a separate thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing the concrete control. But in general, I see 2 options for make such a control MVVM conform:

1. Subclass the control and add dependency properties so it can be used in XAML
2. Create a "container control" that wraps the unMVVMable control and provides the required dependency properties.

However, if the API of the control is complex and has not only properties, but also some methods, it may be pragmatic do break MVVM here. MVVM is not the only way to separate GUI related logic from the view. You could abstract the used functions with an interface and use the interface within your view model for example.

Comment: "without knowing the concrete control" - as I wrote in the question its GMap.NET
"You could abstract the used functions with an interface and use the interface within your view model for example. " - could you be more specific?

Comment: You wrote "GMap.NET"... but a quick search shows only a WinForms control with that name. Do you mean that one? I link to the concrete control were helpful :).

Comment: There is also a WPF one there: https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/  //
https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/tree/master/GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation

Comment: Do you mean [that one](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMapControl.cs)? If so, it makes sense to provide the link in your question ;).